How to Make Only White Areas Metallic While Keeping the Rest Matte and Transparent in Blender?
I’m trying to make only the white areas in the image below appear metallic while keeping the rest of the texture matte and preserving transparency around the badge.
Is there a way to isolate colors to apply metallic or other custom properties?
Any tips on achieving this would be greatly appreciated!


Since you're working with white, it will be very ease.
Plug the texture to a color ramp, left side black, right side white, and adjust the limit as you prefer.
Do a similar thing to the roughness, but using grays instead of black and white. (Black = roughnes 0; White = roughness 1; grays in between)

